# How to make the chat ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

I'm implementing the chat listview in android I'm using scroll listener in my activity to update the chat data.

I'm using the below code to check for the scroll idle state and updating the listview.

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    scrolled=true;
    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= listview.getCount()-1) {
            if(task != null && (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)){
                task = new MessageTask();
                task.execute(new String[]{URL});
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is the listview updates only when i scroll otherwise it does not updates the listview.

So i'm using the timer to schedule calling the asynctask periodically.

How to stop the timer and start the timer again when on scrolling the listview in android.
or is the timer approach correct ? Please advice if there are any other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these to your ListView to achieve what you want.

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="normal"
```